# Express-session changes session id on refresh (Guest login attempt)

Tags: express, session, redis, apollo-server, express-session

I'm trying to create a guest account for a portfolio website so that recruiters can play with it without having to register and set things up, but I need the account to be session or IP specific so that users can have their own guest account without interfering with each other.

I thought about achieving that by using the `sessionID` within `ApolloServer's context.req` as the account name but I've noticed I get a different sessionID on every request/refresh.

My backend's session setup looks like this:

```
  const app = express();

  // Initialize redis sessions server
  const redisConfig = app.get('env') === 'production' ? { host: 'redis' } : undefined; // Change host from default to the name of the docker service (redis) when in production
  const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
  const redisClient = redis.createClient(redisConfig); // This would take the connection parameters, but we leave the default values: https://redislabs.com/lp/node-js-redis/

  // Tell express that we have a proxy in front of our app so that sessions work when using Nginx: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html#express-behind-proxies
  if (app.get('env') === 'production') app.set("trust proxy", 1);

  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
      credentials: true
    })
  );

  app.use(
    session({
      name: COOKIE_NAME,
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
        disableTTL: true, // TTL: time to live, how long the session is active, if we want our sessions to be active permanently until manually disabled.
        disableTouch: true, // Prevent that the TTL is reset every time a user interacts with the server.
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // How long in miliseconds until the cookie expires (10 years)
        httpOnly: app.get('env') === 'production', // Prevents JS in the frontend from accessing the cookie.
        // domain: app.get('env') === 'production' ? 'websitename.com' : undefined,
        secure: app.get('env') === 'production', // Cookie only works in https
        sameSite: 'lax',
      },
      saveUninitialized: false, // Prevents that empty sessions are created.
      secret: `${process.env.SECRET}`,
      resave: false, // False to prevent constant pinging to Redis
    })
  );
```

And in my frontend:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: process.env.API_URL,
    credentials: 'include', // Required for sessions. Sends our cookie back to the server with every request.
  })
});
```

This happens both in my local dev environment and in my deployed `https` website. I've seen similar issues with suggestions about changing the `secure` and `samesite` parameters or the CORS config, but that hasn't worked for me so far.

Any idea of what the issue might be? Is this just not the right approach to do what I'm after?

Sorry if it's something super-obvious, haven't touched my server in months and my backend skills are a bit rusty '^^.

Comment: Try changing `saveUninitialized` to `true`, so empty sessions are actually stored. If that works, you may want to move the session middleware to _after_ any sort of static middleware (or other middleware/route handlers that don't require a session) to prevent too many empty sessions to be saved to your storage.

Comment: That does work, thank you =) The session id still changes with every login/logout even with the same account (as expected?), so I guess I'll have to figure out a way of making it ip-specific and not session-specific so that guests can log back to the same account they were using.

Comment: It could be that the session gets destroyed once the user is logged out, but that would depend on which system you're using for logging in/out users.